# How to run migration script from "HEROKU" to insert data in MongoDB?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean.io

I deployed my app on Heroku that working fine.

Now, I want to run migration scripts from migration folder to Insert some information in mongoDB data base.

Those migration script run successfully locally and insert information's in mongoDB database.

How can I run on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You can run arbitrary scripts on Heroku like this:

```
heroku run node foobar.js
```

eg:

```
heroku run node db/migrate.js
```

Just be sure that your scripts respect the same connection vars (MONGOLAB_URL, DATABASE_URL, etc) that your app does.